# Twin engine helicopters: is the throttle controlled separately for each engine or together?

Tags: helicopter, rotorcraft

There is usually a twist throttle on the collective for a single engine helicopter. On twin engine helicopters, does the twist throttle control it for both engines, or just for one?

Answer (score 2):

Most employ separate throttles, either twist-type, on the collective or levers in an overhead quadrant.

Bell products use duel collective mounted, twist type throttles, in series. Sikorsky uses overhead levers. French SA > AS > Eurocopter > Airbus > Leonardo use levers overhead. Agusta uses overhead levers.

Comment: An example would greatly improve the answer.

Comment: @Walker, are there two separate twist type throttles, or just one (that controls both engines) on Bell helicopters?

Comment: @jeff0000 Yup. Sorry. Bells use two separate twist throttles, in series (See Edit). I don't remember which engine corresponds to the more forward twist-grip vs the more aft twist-grip.